# Why 1 & 1 === 1 returns true while 2 & 2 === 2 returns false?

Tags: javascript, binary, operator-keyword

In the console, when I type `1 & 1` it returns `1`, that's basically why `1 & 1 === 1` returns `true`.

For `2 & 2` it returns `2` but `2 & 2 === 2` returns `false`

Why ?

```js
console.log("1 & 1: ", 1 & 1);
console.log("1 & 1 === 1: ", 1 & 1 === 1);
console.log("2 & 2: ", 2 & 2);
console.log("2 & 2 === 2: ", 2 & 2 === 2);
console.log("typeof(2): ", typeof 2);
console.log("typeof(2 & 2): ", typeof(2 & 2));
```

Comment: It doesn't return `false`, it returns `0`. It's evaluated as `2 & (2 === 2)`. `(2 & 2) === 2` is `true`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Ah yes... got it... Thanks

Comment: for even no. it return 0 for odd no it return 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe said, it doesn't return `false`, it returns `0`. It's evaluated as `2 & (2 === 2)`. `(2 & 2) === 2` is `true`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in javascript when you write 2 & 2 this doesnt mean 2 && 2 instead it convert
2 into 32 bits numbers and perform AND operation, the same AND you learned in binary numbers where the numbers wont be 2 again therefore
(2 & 2) === 2 wont return true,
as (1 & 1) === 1 returns true because on binary operation 1 AND 1 returns 1 as well

Comment: `(2 & 2) === 2` returns `true`.  I know right about binary operators. The answer was about the operator precedence. the comparison operator (`===`) is  prioritary over the binary operator.
In an decomposed state, `2 & 2 === 2` is evaluated as `2 & true`, which is the same as `2 & 1` because true is considered as 1 when evaluated as a number.